# How to give our own custom action inside the camera cancel button in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming. Can any body tell that in camera view before capturing the picture its showing camera button and cancel button?

But in place of cancel button I want to give our own action,where can I give action inside that cancel button. And how to avoid 'use' and 'retake' button in camera.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the camera show button `picker.showsCameraControls = NO;` and draw a custom button over camera API